# Volume of a pyramid in $\mathbb{R^4}$ with five corners at $\langle0,0,0,0\rangle$ and the rows of $I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, volume

> What is the volume of a pyramid in $\mathbb{R^4}$ with five corners at $\langle0,0,0,0\rangle$ and the rows of $I$

**My attempted solution:**

For a triangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$, the following formula gives the volume (area in $\mathbb{R^2}$):

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$

where $\langle x_i, y_i \rangle$ is a vertex of the triangle. Now if you take a close look, you'll notice $A \in \mathbb{R^3}$, while the our triangle is in $\mathbb{R^2}$, this is because our triangle exists in a plane $z = 1$, hence the $1's$ in column three of $A$.

**My Understanding of this formula:** *We need $A$ to be in $\mathbb{R^3}$ as we have three vertices of a triangle in two-dimensions, and we can't take the determinant of a $2 \times 3$ matrix, so instead we take $\mathbb{R^2}$ as a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and calculate the determinant from a $3 \times 3$ matrix.*

Now I tried to generalize this formula for $A \in \mathbb{R^5}$, with our pyramid in $\mathbb{R^4}$, by my (possibly wrong) interpretation of the above formula like so:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 &  z_1 & \alpha_1&  1\\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & \alpha_2& 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & \alpha_3& 1\\
x_4 & y_4 & z_4 & \alpha_4& 1\\
x_5 & y_5 & z_5 & \alpha_5& 1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

where $\langle x_i, y_i, z_i, \alpha_{i} \rangle$ is a vertex of the pyramid in $\mathbb{R^4}$.

Plugging in numbers we get

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 &  0 & 0&  1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1\\
\end{vmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}$$

which is wrong as the correct answer is $\frac{1}{24}$.

---

What have I done wrong? Is my interpretation of the original formula wrong? If so what is the correct interpretation? How can you correctly calculate the volume of a pyramid in $\mathbb{R^4}$?

Comment: well that factor is obviously wrong. Do you know integration in $\mathbb R^n$ and Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @User215257, yes I do

Comment: So your set is $P = \{ x\in\mathbb R^4 \mid x_1,\dotsc,x_4 \ge 0, x_1+\dotsb + x_4 \le 1  \}$. Apply Fubini iteratively until you recognize the measure.

Comment: The determinant without any multiplier is the volume of a hyperparallelepiped.  In case $n=2$, the triangle has half the area.  See if you can tell what happens for $n=3$ before going on to $n=4$.

Comment: @GEdgar Of the face of it it seems like the multiplier into the determinant for a hyperparalellepiped in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $\frac{1}{n!}$, but that is just an observation, I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: The observation is right ... for how to prove it, see user's hints.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume